# f:param tag attribute 'disable' is not work

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, facelets

I try to use `<f:param>` tag to build output link URL with parameters depending on some my conditions.

When I place this tag inside h:output link and try to set different values for 'disable' I see no effect.

Here the my code

```
<h:outputLink value="/WebApplication10/faces/index.xhtml">
    Link1
    <f:param disable="#{true}" name="name1" value="value1"/>            
    <f:param disable="#{false}" name="name2" value="value2"/> 
</h:outputLink>
```

I expect to see only one param in url but I see both.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Using `disable="true"` instead of `disable="#{true}"` works for me.

So, it's either a bug in the [tag documentation](http://javaserverfaces.java.net/nonav/docs/2.1/vdldocs/facelets/f/param.html) that it supports `ValueExpression` or a bug in the `UIParameter` class that it does not resolve it as a `ValueExpression`. I have at least reported [issue 2102](http://java.net/jira/browse/JAVASERVERFACES-2102) for this.

---

**Update**: As a temporary hack/workaround, you could use `<c:if>` to control the inclusion of the `<f:param>` tag during view build time.

```
<h:outputLink value="/WebApplication10/faces/index.xhtml">
    Link1
    <c:if test="#{!true}"><f:param name="name1" value="value1"/></c:if>
    <c:if test="#{!false}"><f:param name="name2" value="value2"/></c:if>
</h:outputLink>
```

Note that this is not going to work when this piece is embedded in a JSF iterated component such as `<ui:repeat>`, `<h:dataTable>` and on and the `test` condition depends on the iterated variable.

Comment: I updated the answer to include a temporary hack/workaround. You could use it until the Mojarra guys have fixed the issue.

Comment: FYI: this is fixed since Mojarra 2.1.15. More than 1.5 years later :/

Answer (score 4):

Use 'disble' instead 'disable'.
The reason is described here:
http://markmail.org/message/bmb2lek5mcx4ofp7

Comment: Better yet, use both, so your application continues to work when it runs on a fixed version of Mojarra.