# Conditional rendering of f:param in JSF

Tags: jsf, jsf-2.2

I'm using an `<h:outputLink>` as follows.

```
<c:set var="cid" value="1"/>
<c:set var="sid" value="2"/>

<h:outputLink value="Test.jsf">
    <h:outputText value="Link"/>

    <f:param name="cid" value="#{cid}"/>
    <f:param name="sid" value="#{sid}"/>
</h:outputLink>
```

<sub>This is just an example. Both of the query-string parameters are dynamic. So, `<c:set>` used here is just for the sake of demonstration.</sub>

At any time, either one, both or none of the parameters may be present. In case, if only one or none of them is present then, parameter/s are unnecessarily appended to the URL which should not happen. Preventing unnecessary query-string parameters from being appended to the URL requires a conditional rendering of `<f:param>`.

JSTL `<c:if>` like the following

```
<c:if test="${not empty cid}">
    <f:param name="cid" value="#{cid}"/>
</c:if>
```

did not work.

How can it be made possible to conditionally render `<f:param>` inside `<h:outputLink>`?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The `<f:param>` has a [`disable` (not `disabled`!) attribute](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/javaserver-faces-2-2/vdldocs-facelets/f/param.html) for the purpose.

```
<f:param name="cid" value="#{cid}" disable="#{empty cid}" />
<f:param name="sid" value="#{sid}" disable="#{empty sid}" />
```

Note that this has a bug in Mojarra versions older than 2.1.15, because they typo'ed the actual `UIParameter` property to be `disble` instead of `disable`. See also [issue 2312](https://java.net/jira/browse/JAVASERVERFACES-2312).

As to the `<c:if>` approach, that would only work if the `#{cid}` and `#{sid}` is available during view build time. In other words, it would fail if they are only available during view render time, e.g. when they depend on `var` of a repeater component. See also [JSTL in JSF2 Facelets... makes sense?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3342984/jstl-in-jsf2-facelets-makes-sense/)

#### See also:

- [f:param tag attribute 'disable' is not work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6298742/fparam-tag-attribute-disable-is-not-work/)

Answer (score 2):

Don't you  like this kind of a solution?

```
<f:param name="#{cid == null ? '' : 'cid'}" value="#{cid}"/>
<f:param name="#{sid == null ? '' : 'sid'}" value="#{sid}"/>
```